Pivot columns into Rows
I am trying to convert data that is shaped like this:
| Manager 1 | Manager 2 | Manager 3 | ...
| team ABC | team BFG | team CXP | ...
| team DEF | team KFC | team BLT | ...

I am trying to convert this into:
| team ABC | Manager 1 |
| team BFG | Manager 2 |
| team CXP | Manager 3 |
| team DEF | Manager 1 |
.
.
.

I am not an Excel expert and not sure what functionality I can use for this. Any suggestions?
Feel free to suggest a better name for this post for future SEO :)

Here is one way of doing this using HSTACK() & TOCOL()


=HSTACK(TOCOL(A2:C3),TOCOL(IF(A2:C3<>"",A1:C1)))



Thank you, that get's me 80% there. But, because each manager does not have the same number of teams, I get a lot of rows with | 0 | FALSE...Do you know how to skip those?

@FailedUnitTest just use this : =HSTACK(TOCOL(A2:C3,1),TOCOL(IFS(A2:C3<>"",A1:C1),2))
